# Restart just one NIC after IP change?

Tags: networking, solaris-10, solaris

I just changed the IP address of `ixgbe0` like so

```
ipadm delete-if ixgbe0
dladm set-linkprop -p mtu=9000 ixgbe0
ipadm create-if ixgbe0
ipadm create-addr -T static -a 10.10.47.46/16 ixgbe0/v4static
```

and normally I would do `svcadm restart network` to active the change, but that would also restart `ixgbe2`, and that may not be interrupted.

I am using OmniOS which is based on Solaris 10.

**Question**

Is it possible to restart just `ixgbe0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svcadm restart network` will not affect the operation of ixgbe2 - I have done this many times on live and test systems running solaris 10 and 11 and never had a problem.

What I don't get it why are you restarting the network service after doing this, just run `dladm show-linkprop -p mtu "datalink"` and it should show the new MTU in affect

Comment: With the command you posted, I see the properties of the NIC interface. But I can still not connect to it from a different host.

Comment: run `dladm show-ether ixgbe0` is should look something like this `net0              current  up       yes   1G-f                            bi`  also is the host you are connecting from have an mtu of 9000

Comment: Yes, taht is what I get. It is MTU 9000.

Comment: `dladm show-link ixgbe0` does this display an MTU of 9000, if it doesn't then run the `svcadm restart network/physical` as i said above this should not interrupt the operation of your other NICs

Comment: Now I understand why you are asking about the MTU 9000. Because it is not default. I'll try restart after working hours, just to be sure =)